# HTTP запрос не выводит данные на экран

Tags: android, http

Занимаюсь http запросом через андроид приложение. Запускаю эмулятор все проходит и даже ошибок никаких не вывод, только после нажатия кнопки выходят 2 строчки : V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 1207 from 5045 (24%)
V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 5045 from 5045 (100%)

Не знаю как двигаться дальше или что исправлять.

код :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnGet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
    btnGet.setOnClickListener(this);
    Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    v.setEnabled(false);
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://serverapi.respect-shoes.kz/ServerAPI/hs/Konversia ", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (responseBody != null) {
                TextView txtResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);
                assert  txtResponse != null;
                txtResponse.setText(new String(responseBody));
            }
            v.setEnabled(true);
        }
            @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            v.setEnabled(true);

        }
    });

}

private class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Уточните, что это за зверь у вас, этот `AsyncHttpClient`.

Comment: Это просто библиотека, если вы об этом

Comment: Тогда спросите ее автора.